# How to dynamically append a webcomponent into ngTemplate

Tags: angular, typescript, web-component

I have an Angular component that has in its html template an ng-template tag:

```
<ng-template #mycontainer></ng-template>
```

in the class I declared an attribute with decorator view-child:

```
@ViewChild('mycontainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) mycontainer: ViewContainerRef;
```

and I have declared a function

```
appendWebComponent(parent: ViewContainerRef, child: HTMLElement) {
  parent.element.nativeElement.appendChild(child);
}
```

but I got an error:

```
ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method.
```

I can't understand why, this function exists in nativeElement object.
If I put my webcomponent directly inside my HTML template it works fine....
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

ng-template native element does not have the method appendChild, use a div, span or any HTML element

or use appendData on ng-template native element

```html
<div #mycontainer></div>
```

```js
appendWebComponent(parent: ViewContainerRef, child: HTMLElement) {
  parent.element.nativeElement.appendData(child);
}
```